# SQL: How do I add specific rows together?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How I would add 2 specific rows in an SQL table together?

For example:

```
    ID    Quantity
    1     1
    1     3
    1     2
    2     3
    2     4
```

I want to be able to add together ID 1 and 2 so the table becomes

```
    ID    Quantity
    1     6
    2     7
```

Comment: `SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity) AS sum FROM your_table GROUP BY ID;` The simplest query using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `SUM` aggregate function and `GROUP BY` the ID.

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Quantity)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ID
```

Output:

```
ID    Quantity
1     6
2     7
```

SQL Fiddle:

[Further Reading.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)